# How do I make a timer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to make a Zombie Pigman grinder (with a spawner not in the nether). I'm going to make it so they get crushed to death by blocks. But what I need help is with the redstone timer. I need to the blocks to crush every 30 seconds, but that redstone pulse needs to be 15 seconds long.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? I bet that a quick Google search would give you tons of answers. See also the [help].

Comment: @FabianRöling: Clocks of specific duty cycle besides the period aren't particularly common, and while a separate clock and pulse extender would work, it's less optimal than a dedicated solution.

Comment: @RacingEcho: Do you mean 15 seconds crushing, 15 not crushing, or 15s crushing, then 30 not crushing?

Comment: @SF. I mean 15 seconds crushing (to kill them) then the blocks stop crushing for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Clocks with customizable duty cycle aren't that common, but it seems like in your case a standard Etho clock could suffice.

57 items provide 45s cycle length. [src](http://monsieurtouf.fr/tools/hopper-timer-calculator).

Using 16-stackable items (eggs, ender pearls, snowballs) - 3 stacks + 9 items - you'll obtain maximum signal strength of 10 [src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI8uO.jpg).

If you draw the signal strength from one of the clock's hoppers with a comparator, and subtract 7 (2 stacks + 3 16-stackable items), you're getting output for about 14 seconds, with 31 seconds inactive. You may tweak the times using the number of items in the hopper but it's difficult to obtain good accuracy simultaneously on duty cycle and clock period.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This should help with your timer and for the crushing:

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.